# Getting and adding specific values to dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Nice to meet you all.

I'm new to Python and I've a "Maze solving" project. The project itself is a bit confusing and Professor wants users to use List for such tasks. The problem is I'm using dictionary to store input values instead of lists because I find dictionaries easier to work with in C#.
This is how I'm storing data:

```
ArcsDict.update({'Arc' + str(InputNum) : {'StartPoint': StartPoint, 'EndPoint': EndPoint, 'Price': Price}} )
```

This is how the dictionary looks:

```
{"Arc1": { "StartPoint" : 1, "EndPoint" : 2, "Price" : 10 }, "Arc2":{"StartPoint" : 3, "EndPoint" : 5, "Price" : 15  }}
```

Now I want to get only StartPoints and EndPoints from the dictionary and add them to another dictionary called NodesDict

```
for val in ArcsDict.keys():
    for value in ArcsDict[val].keys():
        print ArcsDict[val][value]
        NodesDict.update({'Nodes' + str(InputNum) : {'XPoint': ArcsDict[val][value], 'YPoint': ArcsDict[val][value] }})
```

The above code "for loop" stuff sometimes makes sense to me and sometimes it doesn't but is there any way I can ONLY get the StartPoints and EndPoints from each Arc and add them to NodesDict then print the points as:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 3)
```

We are ONLY allowed to use default Python modules.  Any help will be appreciated!

Edit: If anyone could explain how dictionary works in Python in a bit detail that would be appreciated as well! I would like to convince my professor to use dictionary instead of lists while making it sound easier and understandable at the same time.

Comment: If you have a dictionary whose keys are all of the form *XN*, where the *N*s are successive integers, then you *should* be using a list.

Comment: Where did `(0,0)` come from? (It's not in the original dictionary).

Comment: @Andrei That was a question example.

Comment: @ScottHunter But the program has the find the best path based on the price then create nodes (NodesDict AKA Stops) from the Arc tables (ArcsDict Start and End points).
I thought Lists wouldn't be the best way to do so because what Professor did was:
**[(1,1,15)]** which was (StartPoint, End Point, Price) and it didn't seem pleasant.